# Angular-google-maps passing information from info window to parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

Is this possible? Having poured over the documentation, there are extremely few, if any, work arounds to call functions outside of the scope of the marker. My hope is to add some ng-click features, but given that the div inside the infowindow is ng-non-bindable, it prevents implementing any directives. If there isn't a work around, does anyone know if I can use the standard javascript google maps package inside an angular application and support it with jquery?

P.S. If anybody has figured out a way to stylize the info window, please let me know. That has been frustrating.

My goal is to do something like:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options">
  <ui-gmap-markers models="appFact.getList()" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" click="'onClick'" options="'options'">
    <ui-gmap-windows show="show">
      <div ng-non-bindable>
        <h5><strong>{{name}}</strong></h5>
        <h5><strong>{{address}}</strong></h5>
        <a href="" ng-class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="confirmAppointment()"></a>
      </div>
    </ui-gmap-windows>
  </ui-gmap-markers>    
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Where confirmAppointment() would take the the appointment information and post a resource request to the server.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

Different question same fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27322298/3790618
You need to create a separate controller and template. You can pass your function to your window's scope you set your templateParameter.